# cmake equivalent of autoconf AC_ARG_WITH

Tags: cmake, autotools

What's the cmake equivalent of autoconf's AC_ARG_WITH? In autoconf I can us AC_ARG_WITH to create a '--with-' command line argument to configure that lets me pass a path to a SDK and under that path are the headers and libraries. How do I do the same thing in cmake? Should I read the path from an env var?

Answer (score 1):

`cmake` executable accepts variables' definitions in command line in form

```
-D<var_name>[:<TYPE>]=<value>
```

(`:[<TYPE>]` part is noted in [cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html), but it can be omitted).

Such variables are automatically added to the CMake cache, and can be used by project's cmake script.

For 3d-party project's installation path common idiom is:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
find_library(SDK_LIB sdk PATHS ${SDK_DIR} PATH_SUFFIXES lib)
find_path(SDK_INCLUDE_DIR sdk.h PATHS ${SDK_DIR} PATH_SUFFIXES include)
```

If `SDK_DIR` variable is set, its value (with appropriate suffix) will be used  for search SDK library (`SDK_LIB`) and include directory (SDK_INCLUDE_DIR).

If the variable is not set, or search based on it's value has been failed, search will be continued in other places, including system-default ones.

---

Actually, tuning of package's paths in CMake is much more flexible than one provided with `AC_ARG_WITH` in autotools. E.g., one can pass common root(s) of *all* 3d-party packages using `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, or common root(s) for *all* libraries using `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`. See documentation on [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) and other `find_*` commands for more details.

Many of 3d-party packages provide `Find<name>.cmake` and/or `<name>Config.cmake` scripts, so them can be searched simply using [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) command. These scripts (and `find_package` itself) provide ways for tuning search paths, so *your package needn't to bother of path's tuning at all*.